# Java Array Error

Tags: java, arrays

New to java programming and I am currently trying to create a class similar to ArrayList using Arrays.

Am trying to add elements to an array and expand the array by copying them to a new array of bigger size.
I am getting an out of index error at 20.
Code may be messy but currently really stuck.

```
public class MyArrayList{

private String[] strings;
private int arraySize;
private int storedStrings;

public MyArrayList(int arraySize){
    this.arraySize = arraySize;
    this.strings = new String[arraySize];
}

public void addString(String string){
    storedStrings = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.arraySize;i ++){
        if (strings[i] != null){
            storedStrings = storedStrings +1;
        }
    }
    if (storedStrings == this.arraySize){
        String[] newArray = new String[this.arraySize+10];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.strings.length; i++){
            strings[i] = newArray[i];
        }
        this.strings = newArray;
        newArray[storedStrings] = string;
        this.arraySize = this.arraySize +10;
    }
    else{
        strings[storedStrings] = string;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
    {
        //System.out.println(strings[i]);
    }


}
}
```

The code is being run in the test class where the error is being generated on line 10 of test class and line 47 of MyArrayList class.
This is the test code

```
public class TestArrayList{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    MyArrayList a = new MyArrayList(10);

    for (int i = 0; i <50; i++){
        a.addString("Test" + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<50;i++){
        System.out.println(a.getString(i*5));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception? And how do you run this code? I just ran it, and it doesn't throw any Exception.

Comment: I'll add in the test class now

Comment: I dont see a getString(int  i) method in your class

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
public void addString(String string){

    if (storedStrings == this.arraySize){
        this.arraySize += 10;
        String[] newArray = new String[this.arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.storedStrings; i++){
            newArray[i] = strings[i];
        }
        this.strings = newArray;
    }

    if (strings[storedStrings] == null){
        strings[storedStrings++] = string;
    }
    // remove this loop it will show repeating values otherwise
    for(int i = 0; i < storedStrings; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(strings[i]);
    }
}
```

edit: as you are new to java always think about how can you do more with less code, how to avoid repetition of code, how to merge things that do common task. That will help you write better code

edit2 : the problem is with this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i<50;i++){
    System.out.println(a.getString(i*5));
}
```

if you have 50 elements in array the getString method on (eg) i = 25 will be 25*5 = 125 which is not the index in the array that's why you are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception.
you can add

```
public int size(){
    return storedStrings;
}
```

to check the size of your list which is the maximum item that is inside the list

Answer (score 0):

First with your code there is a mistake in this line

```
strings[i] = newArray[i];
```

because you aren´t copying the old data to new array but cleaning the strings array, I suppose that you wish do the contrary action.
In other hand you have extra code that you could improve.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyArrayList{

  private String[] strings;
  private int arraySize;

  public MyArrayList(int arraySize){
    this.arraySize = arraySize;
    this.strings = new String[arraySize];
  }

  public void addString(String string){
    // Since you always do this
    // it's better to use a local variale
    int storedStrings = 0;

    // Use the foreach syntax
    // it's less prone to errors
    // and easier to read
    for (String s : this.strings){
      if (s != null){
        storedStrings++;
      }else{
        // since you want to count the strings in your array
        // and you put them in this array
        // one after the other
        // no need to check the whole array
        // when you find null you can exit the loop
        break;
      }
    }

    if (storedStrings == this.arraySize){
      String[] newArray = new String[this.arraySize+10];
      for (int i = 0; i < this.strings.length; i++){
        // here we need to copy the content of strings in newArray
        // NOT the other way
        newArray[i] = this.strings[i];
      }
      this.strings = newArray;
      newArray[storedStrings] = string;
      this.arraySize += 10;
    }else{
      this.strings[storedStrings] = string;
    }
  }

  public String[] getStrings(){
    return this.strings;
  }
}
```

As for the test class

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  MyArrayList a = new MyArrayList(10);
  for (int i = 0; i <50; i++){
    a.addString("Test" + i);
  }
  for (String s : a.getStrings()){
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```